# Python different results of code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm just beginning to learn and read about Python and have question that I'm having trouble understanding while reading the first few chapters of the book. I came across this while playing around with the interpreter.

Here is my question, how come the values differ in both of these expressions. In the first example, the value of `y` remains the same after changing `x`, while in the next example when changing `x`, it also changes the value of `y`.

Example 1:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> y = x
>>> x += 1
>>> x
6
>>> y
5
```

Example: 2

```
>>> x = [5]
>>> y = x
>>> x[0] = 6
>>> x
[6]
>>> y
[6]
```

Comment: `x + 1` or `x += 1`? (just a tip, not the problem)

Comment: Yes, x+=1 sorry edited.

Answer (score 4):

Its about `python reference`.When

```
a = [2]
b = a
```

Here `a`, and `b` both referencing to `[2]`.You can check it by `id`

```
>>>id(a)
3066750252L

>>>id(b)
3066750252L
```

Both are same ids. So `a.append` or `b.append` will affect both `a` and `b`.That is `[2]`.This is in case of `mutable` objects.So `a[0]=6` will affect `b` also.In case of integers, it will not affect since, `int` is `immutable` object.So

```
>>>a = 2
>>>id(a)
164911268
>>>a = a + 1
>>>a
3
>>>id(a)
164911256
```

Here `id` changed.That means new `int` object is created `3`.It is now referencing by variable `a`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

The value of the two objects in question differs, one, the `int` is ***immutable*** while the other, the `list` is mutable.

By assigning both names `x, y` to `5` you create two different ***names*** for the same value `5`. When you perform an operation:

```
In [1]: x = y = 5

In [2]: x = x + 1

In [3]: x
Out[3]: 6

In [4]: y
Out[4]: 5
```

`x+1` *returns a new* `int` object because you cannot change the value of an int.

`list` types on the other hand are mutable. So when you create two names that reference the same list and then change the value of its contents with assignment via `x[0] = 1` it simply affects the list being referenced by `x` and doesn't create a new list. So, results of this assignment are visible to `y` too because *they reference the same* ***mutable*** object:

```
In [11]: x = y = [5]

In [12]: x[0] = 1

In [13]: x
Out[13]: [1]

In [14]: y
Out[14]: [1]
```

Note that adding `x = x + [1]` will create a new list, what you are doing with `x[0]=1` is simply changing the contents. Take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns) presentation for a more complete coverage.